# Archlinux bluetile failed to install "glade"

Tags: arch-linux

When I try to install bluetile in archlinux, I get the following error:

```
 Building glade-0.12.1...
 Preprocessing library glade-0.12.1...
 gtk2hsC2hs: UName: root name supply used after saving
 cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
 bluetile-0.6 depends on glade-0.12.1 which failed to install.
 glade-0.12.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
 ExitFailure 1
```

I'm using the [ArchLinux Wiki install instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetile).

Answer (score 1):

According to a [thread on gmane.comp.lang.haskell.gtk2hs.devel](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.gtk2hs.devel/1274), the problem is with gtk2hs-buildtools-0.12.3.  0.12.1 doesn't have the problem.

I fixed the issue myself by installing 0.12.1:

```
cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools==0.12.1
```

and the error you describe goes away.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get `cabal: The program alex is required but it could not be found. Error: some packages failed to install...` Which is weird, because I HAVE alex installed!